# how to add tex to octave graph

Tags: octave, tex

I have a bar graph, and I am using text() to display fractions above each of the bars.  For example:

```
text(1, 20, "300/400")
```

displays the string "300/400" at position (1,20).

I would now like to prettify the fractions so that "300" appears *over* the "400":

```
300
---
400
```

Is there a way to do this, eg with tex or latex?

I tried each of these, but the interpreter is not getting called:

```
text(1, 20, '\frac{300}{400}');
text(1, 20, '\frac{300}{400}', 'interpreter', 'tex');
text(1, 20, '\frac{300}{400}', 'interpreter', 'latex');
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's not yet possible in Octave. The TeX interpreter doesn't support the \frac structure, and the LaTeX interpreter isn't yet implemented.

http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_172.html