# (converting MATLAB script to Octave script) LaTeX rendering in output plot

Tags: matlab, latex, octave

I am in the process of converting a Matlab script to an Octave one. I have pretty much completed the task - however, I am having problems using a particular LaTeX command to print out correctly.

I changed the line in the m script from:

```
ylabel('Foobar $F=\frac{A}{B}$','Fontsize',20,'FontWeight','Bold','interpreter','latex');
```

To

```
ylabel('Foobar $F=\frac{A}{B}$','Fontsize',20,'FontWeight','Bold','interpreter','tex');
```

However, this does not render correctly (the original character display on the plot - complete with the format specifiers).

I don't understand why this is the case, since I am successfully using LaTeX commands in the same plot - and those work correctly.

Is there something wrong with the LaTeX commands above?. It is supposed to render as a fraction (A over B).

Comment: Similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075575/how-to-add-tex-to-octave-graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command renders fine for me (using Matlab).  The second does not.

Generally `'tex'` expresses lower level concepts than `'latex'`.  This demonstrates that the `frac` construct is not available in the `'tex'` interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you have a link to back up that assertion?. It could also simply be due to the fact that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: List of tex commands:  www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html  (no "frac" defined)

List of latex commands (with "frac"):  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Commands